# Drake installation issue on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drake

I'm following Drake's installation instructions from [here](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/drake.html) for ubuntu.

I get stuck at this line:

```
python3 -c 'import pydrake; print(pydrake.__file__)'
```

with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from . import common
  File "/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/common/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._module_py import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.common._module_py'
```

What is the ._module_py file? I don't see it in:

```
/opt/drake/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydrake/common
```

The python version I've got installed is 3.8.5, but I don't think that's causing any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you linked to say `curl -o drake.tar.gz https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/drake/nightly/drake-latest-bionic.tar.gz`.  The "bionic" there is Ubuntu's codename for 18.04.  If you are using Ubuntu 20.04, then the codename is "focal", so you should use start from `curl -o drake.tar.gz https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/drake/nightly/drake-latest-focal.tar.gz` so that you have Python 3.8 support.

Here are Drake's own installation instructions for pydrake, which are usually the most up-to-date reference: https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#installation